# Menu with in-line items combined with sub-menu with drop-down items in `razor`-`cshtml`

Tags: html, razor

I am struggling to put in place a horizontal menu with in-line items together with a sub-menu with drop-down items that unfolds upon hovering on the menu item.

Here is what I tried in the Site.css file:

```
/* menu
----------------------------------------------------------*/
ul#menu {
    text-align: right;
}

    ul#menu li {
        display: inline;
        list-style: none;
    }

        ul#menu li a {
            background: none;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        ul#menu li a:hover {
            text-decoration: none;
        }

/* sub-menu
----------------------------------------------------------*/
ul#sub-menu {
    text-align: left;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
}

    ul#menu li:hover #sub-menu {
        display: block;
    }

    ul#sub-menu li {
        list-style: none;
        display: block;
    }

        ul#sub-menu li a {
            text-decoration: none;
            display: block;
        }

        ul#sub-menu li a:hover {
            text-decoration: none;
        }
```

Here is the layout that I am trying to put in the _SiteLayout.cshtml file:

```
<nav>
    <ul id="menu">
        <li><a href="~/">Home</a></li>
        <li id="sub-menu"><a href="#">Services</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="~/Service1">Service 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="~/Service2">Service 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="~/Service3">Service 3</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="~/About">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="~/Contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

However, in the end, the layout covers three lines (aligned on the right), the sub-items ('Service 1', 'Service 2', 'Service 3') not being nested under the menu item 'Services'.

```
                    Home   Services
Service 1    Service 2    Service 3
                   About    Contact
```